# Data Collection Solutions

Tags: gps, editing, software-recommendations, data-collection, timestamp

I am seeking a new data collection software for a team of biologists who track migrating animals from planes through aerial telemetry.  I currently use Delorme TOPO USA but when collecting point data the time stamp field is maintained as "date modified" causing errors the the analysis of the data.  The typical data collection softwares I have tried in all of the similar questions do not work because they fail to meet one or more of our criteria that must be met. The current preference is for software compatible with Windows 7 based laptops. The criteria are as follows:

1. Must be able to track current GPS Location with a refresh rate of 3 or less seconds.  (We are in planes and moving quickly).
2. Must be able to manually place waypoint on map.  We are not collecting current locations.  We are collecting locations of animals based on predicted position of an animal relative to current position.
3. Must be able to obtain/import offline maps at several zoom levels for an area that covers most of the midwestern US that  are able to refresh at a rate that keeps up with the planes movements.  Working online is not an option.
4. Must have a topo option for maps that roads/towns/other reference points that can be overlay on map.  USGS does not typically offer enough detail for our purposes.
5. Must maintain the seconds field in the time stamp for speed calculations.
6. Must be able to edit/delete points easily with as few operations as possible.  Erroneous points happen and must be able to remove and move on quickly to determine next location within a minute or so.
7. Must be able to quickly identify a name for asset as there time when there are multiple animals of the same species being tracked and they need to be differentiated.
8. Editing a point cannot edit time fields, or a "date created" field needs be maintained.
9. It would be nice if it had some navigation capabilities because we have a ground crew tracking at the same time and its beneficial to have every team on same software.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the founder of the company responsible for developing this app.

I know this is an old question, but I want to put forward a mobile app that could be used by your team: the [Coral App](https://chaac.tech/coralapp/?utm_medium=Answers&utm_campaign=Seo%20optimization).

It is available on both Android and IOS. You can customize your forms on a web dashboard, collect data efficiently in the field and export your data after your operation.

To address your requirements:

- You can connect an external Bluetooth GPS and use its location on the mobile device. We have people who use the app in a helicopter and the refresh rate is more than enough for their work.
- By default, the collected data is located at the current location, but you can easily move it by clicking on the map and place it at the desired location.
- The app is offline first and you can download offline maps.
- All collected data contains metadata that includes the creation time with seconds.
- You can edit and delete points on the map simply by clicking on them.
- You can customize the label on each point based on the form data. You can also customize the marker's color based on the same principle.
- In the metadata, the "date created" field is not changed when you edit a point.
- There are a few navigation features that were added to optimize the usage in a helicopter.

You should give it a try, there is a free plan for small projects. All plans also include unlimited users.

[image]

Comment: Are you involved in any way with this app?

Comment: Yes, I am the founder of the company responsible for the app development. I am also involved in the development myself. I started this company after many years working as a GIS expert and field data manager during oil spill responses.

Comment: Please, include in your answers a Disclaimer to mention that you are the founder of the company responsible for the app development, otherwise your answers would be treated as advertising and consequently deleted.

Comment: Done! Thank you for the comment.